# How would I print out errors?

Tags: error-handling, lua, compiler-errors, roblox

In the software called Roblox studio I need help making a script that whenever an error happens in game, it would print out the error again using the normal print function something like this example here:

```lua
Local error = —-whatever the error that happened was

Print(error) —- so it just simply prints it back out
```

Comment: Are you looking to handle compiler errors or runtime errors?

Comment: You should honestly post this on the Roblox DevForum, not Stack Overflow. You'll get much more help that way.

Answer (score 1):

Roblox provides a few different ways to keep track of when errors are thrown in your Scripts and LocalScripts.

If you want to observe errors locally in a script, and you know a specific chunk of code may throw errors, you can use [pcall()](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html) as a try-catch block.

```
local success, result = pcall(function()
    error("this is a test error message")
end)
if not success then
    print("An error was thrown!")
    print(result) --"this is a test error message"
end
```

If you want to observe errors across all of your scripts, you can attach a callback to the [ScriptContext.Error signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ScriptContext/Error). This signal fires any time any error is thrown. It provides information about the error, including the message, the callstack, and a reference to the script that threw the error.

**Warning** : `ScriptContext.Error` only fires in the context of the script that registers it. A Script will only observe errors thrown in server scripts, and registering in a LocalScript will only observe errors thrown on the client.

```
local ScriptContext = game:GetService("ScriptContext")
ScriptContext.Error:Connect( function(message, stack, context)
    print("An error was thrown!")
    print("Message : ", message)
    print("Stack : ", stack)
    print("Context :", context:GetFullName())
end)
```

Similarly, if you only care about the error messages themselves, you can also observe them being printed out to the Output window using the [LogService.MessageOut signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/LogService/MessageOut). This signal fires any time anything is logged to Output. This includes messages, warnings, and errors.

```
local LogService = game:GetService("LogService")
LogService.MessageOut:Connect( function(message, messageType)
    if messageType == Enum.MessageType.MessageError then
        print("An error was thrown!")
        print(message)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the stderr stream from `io` library to print debug messages.

```lua
-- Define debug function based in print
function debug(...) io.stderr:write(table.concat({...}, '\9') .. '\n') end

-- Debug acts as a regular "print()", but it writes to stderr instead
debug('[filename.lua]', 'debug')
```

Use "error()" function to print errors.

```lua
if true then
    error("It should not be true!")
end
```

If you want to catch errors from a function, use `xpcall()`

```lua
-- Define debug
function debug(...) io.stderr:write(table.concat({...}, '\9') .. '\n') end

xpcall(
    function()
        local b = {}
        -- This will throw an error because you cant index nil values
        print(a.b)
    end, 
    function(err)
        debug('[xpcall]', err)
    end
)
```

`xpcall()` wont stop the execution in case of error, so you only need to encapsulate your code in it if you want to catch any unexpected errors at runtime.